# Auto capitalization of first letter of a sentence is not working when we use swipe keyboard in android device

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, swipe, capitalization

In my app I used TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES for the edittext,

```
etMessage.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

it is working with the default keyboard in every devices and emulator. But when we use swipe keyboard the capitalization is not happening. Client wants it to work everytime. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue??.

Comment: just that keyboard? could be that keyboard is at fault.

Comment: only with the swipe softkeyboard..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@didnh's response is correct.

You are *asking* for `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES`. Any given input method editor (a.k.a., soft keyboard) can honor or ignore your request.

File a bug report with the makers of the keyboard that is causing you difficulty and explain to the client that it is the keyboard's fault.